# Colorbars for 2D plots using Numpy, Matplotlib and os (rendering probelm)?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have multiple `.plx` files that contain two column of numbers formatted as strings (1.plx , 2.plx...)
I managed to modify a code to load the data, convert it to floats, and plot it with the appropriate colorbar, but there are two issues I couldn't solve:

1. The color of the lines does not update
2. The lines rendering looks wrong (probably due to duplicates)

I want to try to avoid that rendering problem by plotting a numpy matrix, so I want to :

1. Load the data
2. store it in a numpy matrix (outside the loop so that I can do other data processing stuff)
3. create a 2D plot with the colorbar

Here is my attempt and the result:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import os
IdVg = [IdVg for IdVg in os.listdir() if IdVg.endswith(".plx")]

n_lines = 20

steps = np.linspace(0.1, 50, 20)

norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=steps.min(), vmax=steps.max())
cmap = mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=mpl.cm.BuPu)
cmap.set_array([])

for i in IdVg:
    x, y = np.loadtxt(i, delimiter=' ', unpack=True, skiprows= 1, dtype=str)
    x = x.astype(np.float64)
    y = y.astype(np.float64)
    for z, ai in enumerate(steps.T): # Problem here, I want to store x, y values in a 40XN matrix
                                     # (x1, y1, x2, y2...x20, y20) and find a way to plot them
                                     # using Matplotlib and numpy
        plt.plot(x, y, c=cmap.to_rgba(z+1))
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(0, 0))
plt.xlabel('$V_{GS}$ (V)', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('$I_{DS}$ (A)', fontsize=14)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize='12')
plt.grid(True, which="both", ls="-")
plt.colorbar(cmap, ticks=steps)
plt.show()
```

Thanks !

[image]

Comment: You want something like this to create the numpy array...  `X = np.zeros((40, N)); for i in IdVg: X[i, :] = x.astype(no.float64)`

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide data, I'm going to generate my own. I assume you want to obtain the following result:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import os

n_lines = 20
steps = np.linspace(0.1, 50, 20)

norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=steps.min(), vmax=steps.max())
norm_steps = norm(steps)
cmap = mpl.cm.BuPu

plt.figure()
x = np.linspace(0, np.pi / 2)
for i in range(n_lines):
    y = i / n_lines * np.sin(x)
    plt.plot(x, y, c=cmap(norm_steps[i]))
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(0, 0))
plt.xlabel('$V_{GS}$ (V)', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('$I_{DS}$ (A)', fontsize=14)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize='12')
plt.grid(True, which="both", ls="-")
plt.colorbar(mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=mpl.cm.BuPu), ticks=steps)
plt.show()
```

Obviously, you would have to change the colormap to something more readable in the lower values!

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it does not represent my case. the code you wrote does not load data, thus you have one for loop only. that's why I want to break out of the loop by storing the data in a matrix.

Comment: This answers the hard part of what you are asking for.  The rest is simply how you decide to organize your data.